# Someone else editing code in my question :: Highlight Edits

Tags: feature-request

On my last question.. [Creating arrays in for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114641/creating-arrays-in-for-loops-without-creating-an-endless-loop-that-ruins-my-d)

Someone kept editing the code in my question. This caused a different interpretation of my question to the next few visitors. This caused others to answer what is essentially now the editors question and not my first question.

There needs to be some way to show the differences between my original question and the edits of another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you can do is notify others by leaving comment, or re-editing back to your original.

Answer (score 3):

Are you speaking about the revisions 2 and 3? If yes, I don't see any breaking changes in there except formatting changes.

If you mean revision 5, then yes, there are breaking changes. But look at the time of the edit, that was a racing condition, no one to blame.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "edited 4 mins ago" (or whatever) and it shows you a complete set of revisions: who they were by, the comment (if any), a diff, an option to see the raw source, etc.

Comment: Thanks! But I still think that editing code changes the context of a question.. which changes the outcome of the answers. My question was answered, but I had a few people telling me to change my code from what he wrote, to what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to view the edit by clicking on "x mins ago" label where it mentions edited by.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5114641/revisions) you can see changes to your question.